# React.PropTypes not working in function components

Tags: reactjs

I am testing ReactJS. Everything is working properly but React.PropTypes. here is the code:

```
   const MenuItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <li className="list-group-item">
            <span className="badge">{props.price}</span>
            <p>{props.item}</p>
        </li>
    )
}

MenuItem.propTypes = {
    price: React.PropTypes.number
};
```

When I send string to the component there isn't any warning or errors. Not different which PropTypes I use.

- Visual Studio Code
- ReactJS
- babel-standalone

What is my mistake? Thanks a lot

**Edit:**
It's not working even I use PropTypes with React.Component!

Comment: What do you pass into `item` prop?

Comment: Just a text like item = "Tea" ,  price  = 7. And React show them properly in UI. But if I change price to "7" or "seven" PropTypes.number doesn't show warning or error and I still see the string in UI. Thanks

Comment: PropType warnings are only shown in development mode. Are you running in development mode or are you running a static production build of you app?

Comment: I am learning ReatJs with React.js Succinctly ebook. It says "React will give us an explicit warning about it in the console".

Comment: It's true that React will give you "an explicit warning in the console", but only in dev mode. If you are running the production build of your code, React will _not_ output propTypes (or any other, to my knowledge) warnings to the console.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. When I use react.js instead of react.min.js the warnings appeared in chrome dev tools. react.js is the React dev mode. Thanks.

Comment: Adding this as an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

propType warnings aren't showing in the console because you're using the production build of React. They only show in dev mode (the un-minified React export).

To be clear, this is *not* an issue with Functional Components - propTypes can be set on them as they are in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use class properties you should probably use a class.

class MenuItem extends React.Component {...}

See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html.

Comment: I am learning ReatJs with React.js Succinctly ebook. In page 37 there is an example about a stateless component with React.PropTypes for it!

Comment: It's not working even I use React.PropTypes with React.Component! Thanks

Comment: Does React.js Succunctly have working code examples?

Comment: Yes. A stateless component with React.PropTypes like my codes. And it says you can see the warning in JavaScript console. I expect to see warnings in developer tools in chrome. Am I right?

Comment: Can confirm that setting propTypes on stateless components is a standard practice and works fine.

Comment: I stand corrected. I already started some refactoring based on getting a better understanding of stateless functional components.